# Reading numerous html tables into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I'm trying to pull html data tables into a single data frame, and I'm looking for an elegant solution. There are 255 tables, and the urls vary by two variable: Year and Aldermanic District.  I know there must be a way to use for loops or something, but I'm stumped.

I have successfully imported the data by reading each table in with a separate line of code, but this results in a line for each table, and again, there are 255 tables.

```r
library(XML)
data <- bind_rows(readHTMLTable("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/2018_RVS_Dist14.htm", skip.rows=1),
                   readHTMLTable("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/2017_RVS_Dist14.htm", skip.rows=1),
                   readHTMLTable("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/2016_RVS_Dist14.htm", skip.rows=1),
                   readHTMLTable("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/2015_RVS_Dist14.htm", skip.rows=1),
```

Ideally, I could use a `for` loop or something so I wouldn't have to hand code the `readHTMLTable` function for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a vector containing all the URLs which you want to scrape, and then iterate over those inputs using a `for` loop:

```
url1 <- "http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/"
url2 <- "_RVS_Dist"
years <- c(2015:2018)
dist <- c(1:15)
urls <- apply(expand.grid(paste0(url1, years), paste0(url2, dist)), 1, paste, collapse="")
data <- NULL
for (url in urls) {
    df <- readHTMLTable(url)
    data <- rbind(data, df)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The problem with this is that I still have to write all the URLs--I'm looking for a solution that automates the iteration of the URLs.

Comment: @Pecners I gave you an option to generate URLs across all years and districts.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map_dfr` from the `purrr` package (part of the `tidyverse`) package to apply the `readHTMLTable` function across the URL. The key is to identify the part that is different from each URL. In this case `2015:2018` is the only thing changed, so we can construct the URL with `paste0`. `map_dfr` would automatically combine all data frame to return one combined data frame. `dat` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

dat <- map_dfr(2015:2018,
               ~readHTMLTable(paste0("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/",
                                     .x,
                                     "_RVS_Dist14.htm"), skip.rows = 1)[[1]])
```

**Update**

Here is the way to expand the combination between year and numbers, and then download the data with `map2_dfr`.

```
url <- expand.grid(Year = 2002:2018, Number = 1:15)

dat <- map2_dfr(url$Year, url$Number,
               ~readHTMLTable(paste0("http://assessments.milwaukee.gov/SalesData/",
                                     .x,
                                     "_RVS_Dist",
                                     .y,
                                     ".htm"), skip.rows = 1)[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  That works for the years, but the district also varies, ranging 1:15 (the "14" in the URL).  Could I use this method for years ranging 2002:2018 for districts ranging 1:15?

Comment: Pass the districts as a second argument with `map2_dfr(arg1, arg2, fun)`. Refer to it using `.y` where relevant inside `paste` above  and you're done